# Ionic: show back icon instead of menu icon

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a project where i use a side menu and ion-tabs. You can have a small 
example opening this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dLHDlzo5lbdToRC5rORn?p=preview). As you can see you have a side menu and a button (`text`). If you click on that button you will get navigated to the tabs view with three tabs inside it.

My problem now is that at the top left corner the menu icon is shown instead of the back button. That is really not what i want. I want the menu icon to hide when there is a back view and only to show if there is no back view.

Im an Android user and for me the side menu should always work like in android. Ok in android you never have the back button at the top left corner but thats required because the app im developing should also run on ios. So what i need is:

```
- side menu available from each view by sliding it in from left to right
- side menu icon when there is no back view
- back icon instead of menu icon when there is a back view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of issues regarding navigation, history, back button, especially working with tabs.

You can read a comment to this [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2997) from one of the developers:

> Regarding transitions between a non-tabs view and a tabs view, in the
>   current architecture this is challenge due to how the tabs are nested,
>   and a tab is nested inside of tabs. A lot of the limitations are due
>   to how the leaving view is the container for the entering view. The
>   core structure to how transitions and animations works will updated in
>   Ionic 2.0 to allow for any transition between any view. I'm going to
>   change this milestone to 2.0.

and again, [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/437):

> The back button does not display because when you go into a tab, it
>   enter's it own "history", meaning each tab has its own navigation back
>   and forward.

I've opened myself a few issues on this topic.

I guess we will have to wait a few months more.

Comment: Thank you! Right now that kinda annoys me. I had much trouble with that the last days. I just dont understand why they enter another history when opening up tabs. That is really not neccessary. I will have to find a way to avoid that.

Comment: You can try and define your own navigation system using custom head bars. It's not going to be easy. Documentation is poor but there are a good number of tutorials on the Internet. I would suggest you to start with a simple project.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is a common problem with ionic:

[Back button does not appear when navigating to nested view #437](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/437)

I hope that a fix will come soon.